# Dropdownchecklist creating subgroups

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have list which is using dropdownchecklist I want to create subgroups from the element of the list.
So if I click to subgroup checkbox it will check all of the elements which are binds to it.

**My PHP genereated HTML code:**

```
<select name="data[EcnRequests][groups][]" id="groupSelection" multiple="" style="display:   none;">
<option id="group_0" style="background-color: #eee;">All</option>

<option name="groupBy" id="group_A" style="background-color: #eee;"> A_ALL </option>
<option name="groupBy" id="group_B" style="background-color: #eee;"> B_ALL </option>

<option id="group_194">A_A</option>
<option id="group_195">A_B</option>
<option id="group_196">A_C</option>
<option id="group_197">A_D</option>
<option id="group_198">B_A</option>
<option id="group_199">B_B</option>
<option id="group_201">B_C</option>
<option id="group_202">C_A</option>

</select>
```

**My jQuery:**
I tried this but the refresh don't let to check the checkboxes

```
    $j("#groupSelection").dropdownchecklist({firstItemChecksAll: true, emptyText: "Select groups", width: 180,  maxDropHeight: 200,

         onComplete: function(checkbox,selector) {
          $j('#EcnRequestsAdvancedSearchForm').submit();
        },

        onItemClick: function(checkbox, selector){

            var justChecked = checkbox.prop("checked");

            if(checkbox.val().match(/_ALL/g)!=null){


                if (justChecked){

                    arrayFromPHP[checkbox.val().split("_")[0]].forEach(function(e) {
                        console.log(selector.options[11].selected);
                        $j('#groupSelection > option[id=group_'+e+']').prop('selected', true);
                        $j('#groupSelection').dropdownchecklist("refresh");

                    });

                }
                else {
                    arrayFromPHP[checkbox.val().split("_")[0]].forEach(function(e) {
                        $j('#groupSelection > option[id=group_'+e+']').prop('selected', false);
                        $j('#groupSelection').dropdownchecklist("refresh");
                    });

                }

            }
        }


    });
```

**My arrayFromPhp:**

```
Object {A: Array[4], B: Array[3] }
A: Array[4]
0: 194
1: 195
2: 196
3: 197
length: 4
B: Array[3]
0: 199
1: 200
2: 201
length: 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution:**

```
    $j("#groupSelection").dropdownchecklist({firstItemChecksAll: true, emptyText: "Select groups", width: 180,  maxDropHeight: 200,

    onComplete: function(checkbox,selector) {
          $j('#EcnRequestsAdvancedSearchForm').submit();
    },

    onItemClick: function(checkbox, selector){

        var justChecked = checkbox.prop("checked");

        if(checkbox.val().match(/_ALL/g)!=null){
            var id = checkbox.val().split("_")[0];

            if (justChecked){

                $j('#groupSelection > option[id=group_'+id+']').attr('selected', 'selected');

                arrayFromPHP[id].forEach(function(e) {

                    $j('#groupSelection > option[id=group_'+e+']').attr('selected', 'selected');

                });
            }

            else {

                $j('#groupSelection > option[id=group_'+id+']').removeAttr('selected');
                arrayFromPHP[checkbox.val().split("_")[0]].forEach(function(e) {
                    $j('#groupSelection > option[id=group_'+e+']').removeAttr('selected');
                });
            }
            $j('#groupSelection').dropdownchecklist("refresh");
        }
    }


});
```